# How long should notification be stored in a system

Tags: notification, time, duration

Hye,

I'm designing a management tool for admin and an app for user they managed.

I'm not sure of how long should the notification be stored before expiry?
In the app, I suggest to use a 30-day interval, so notification will no longer show up in the notification list after 30 days. This is due to the fact that many activities has been resolved after 30 days.

I'm having issue with the management tool for admin since its a one-account-for-all-admin, they will receive much higher volume of notification compared to the individual user in mobile app.

Should the admin tool notification follows the 30 day convention or change to something like after 100 notification, it will no longer displayed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: More context is needed to answer this question. What problem do the notifications solve for the user? Are there any technical constraints? Because it looks like you've trouble implementing a solution because it's not solving the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think notifications should be displayed for an unlimited amount of time on any platform.

- To solve the number of notifications a user is receiving you can allow them to customize the type of notifications they receive.
- Try grouping notifications too, this will help you categorize the importance of a notification.

As a user, I'm always annoyed when I'm clicking an old email from a notification in a platform and I return to that platform to find out I cannot read the details of that notifications. I always wonder if I have been hacked and someone accessed my account.